# Zend Framework - Redirect to routed direction

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a small problem with PHP Zend Framework.
I have the following routes in file application.ini:

```
resources.router.routes.mainpage.route = "main-page.html"
resources.router.routes.mainpage.defaults.controller = "index"
resources.router.routes.mainpage.defaults.acion = "index"
```

If i do a direct in any action:

```
$this->_helper->redirector('index', 'index');
```

then i will be redirect to adress: **my-project/public/index/index**
But i want to adress be a **my-project/public/main-page.html** (as it is determined application.ini)

Can somebody help me?
P.S.
Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use gotToUrl methods from [Redirector helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html)

```
$this->_redirector = $this->_helper->getHelper('Redirector');
$this->_redirector->gotoRoute(
        array('fooRouteArgument' => fooValue),
        'route-name'
);
```

For your case this result in:

```
$this->_redirector->gotoRoute(array(), 'mainpage');
```

Answer (score -2):

First of all, it seems your syntax in your application.ini is wrong. See [ZF-Manual: Resource Router](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.router)

In your case it would bes sth. like:

```
resources.router.routes.mainpage.route = "/index"
resources.router.routes.mainpage.defaults.controller = "index"
resources.router.routes.mainpage.defaults.acion = "MainPage"
```

However, it seems you're trying to redirect to a static page, which is not part of ZF. `Zend_Controller_Router` can only route to Controllers within your project, as far as I know.

If so, you could simply add the following to redirect:

```php
//In view-scripts:
<?php echo $this->baseUrl('main-page.html'); ?>
//In controllerActions:
$this->_helper->getHelper('Redirector')
        ->gotoUrl('/main-page.html');
```

Comment: Let me suggest you to read the manual because your answer is totally wrong. The main objective of routes is use it as alias of path using for that the route name.

Comment: Thanks, but the objective of routes is quite clear to me. I understood user2225468 main problem to be, that she/he wants to establish a route to a static page and not to a a controller-action. Also, he set `resources.router.routes.mainpage.route` to where the route should go to. But `resources.router.routes.mainpage.route` should have the rule on which router becomes active.