# nginx: remove /index from url

Tags: php, zend-framework, nginx

I setup Zend Framework 1 application running on nginx.  Rewrites work as expected, but the homepage mysite.com redirects to mysite.com/index .  How can the /index be removed?

Here is the vhost config :

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name local-mysite.com;
  root /var/www/mysite/public_html;

  location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
  }

  # PHP scripts will be forwarded to fastcgi processess.
  location ~ \.php$ {
   include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this all your config?

Answer (score 0):

If this is all your nginx config, it must be something related to Zend Framework.

Please take a look at this dicussion:

[Zend Framework - Redirect to routed direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15717440/zend-framework-redirect-to-routed-direction)